# Angular.js scope issues during template loading

Tags: angularjs

I've a two directives with transcluding html which calls isolated scope.

This [Plnkr](http://embed.plnkr.co/BxzZq4uP1G0utk6NN9Ys/preview) works fine while templates are inline, but if I change template to templateURL, it [stops work](http://embed.plnkr.co/R0CKYsaCjb12Q3yG0427/preview).

Are there any issues with compiling?

Answer (score 1):

Loading the template use URL, Angularjs creates an additional transcluded scope I guess.

Try to use `$$prevSibling.$$prevSibling` to access the functions.

Btw, it is really **hacky** to use `$$prevSibling`.

```
<div authorization><a href="#" ng-click="$$prevSibling.$$prevSibling.modalToggle()">Sign in</a></div>
<div registration><a href="#" ng-click="$$prevSibling.$$prevSibling.modalToggle()">Registration</a></div>
```

Comment: Thanks it works, but are there any angular ways of doing it? I'm feel like I'm doing some hacking rather than using the framework.

Comment: I've checked, that's a nice approach, but little different, you transclude popup content in-place of directive, but I prefer to give directive a normal `<a>` tag, which we can change at anytime. So my approach is inverse of yours.